# May I use "usually" with a past-tense verb?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

Usually means in most situations or what most people do.  Is this sentence correct, with the verb in past tense?

> I usually went home late.

Comment: Sounds fine.  If you are (also) asking whether the use of the Past Tense is appropriate, then the answer is "it depends".  In other words, not enough information to answer more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

As @Victor comments, OP's example usage is fine. But in practice, if you say you *usually did* something (past tense), that probably implies you don't do it any more.

A closely-related usage which more strongly forces the *not any more* sense is...

> *I **used to** go home late*

...where it's important to note that (technically speaking) the past tense is in ***used***, so past tense ***went*** becomes infinitive ***go*** because you can't have both verbs tensed here.

It might be interesting to note that you can (contrive to) overrule the *not any more* implication...

> *I **used to** win at Monopoly, and I still do*
>    *I **usually** won at Monopoly, and I still do*

...but that would be slightly "odd" phrasing. Most people would just use present tense...

> *I **usually win** at Monopoly*

Note that there's no equivalent present tense ***use*** version - the closest you can get is...

> *I **am used to winning** at Monopoly*

---

At the risk of straying too far from OP's ***usually***, I'll just point out that in this context, ***use*** is a [defective verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb) (that's why there's no "present tense equivalent" above). And in a construction like...

> *Did you **use** to go home late?*

...hardly anyone really knows (or cares) whether they're actually saying ***used*** (which is even more indistinguishable to a *listener*). Obviously if you stop to *think* about it, ***use*** has to be an infinitive, just as it would be ***like***, not ***liked***. But because we're so much more ***used to*** the past form for this sense, and the distinction doesn't exist in spoken *(real)* language, usage is somewhat flexible...

> *Did you used to [do something or other, in the past]?* [(897 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22did%20you%20used%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...where most of those are probably the "grammatically incorrect" usage.